# How to convert multiple xml files into one csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, csv

I am trying to convert around 200 of my XML files in a folder into single CSV, but I'm stuck with some of my code.
but i always run into this problem when i run the code

> TypeError: writeToCSV() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

i did try to delete the `file_id` but after that the error comes with

> KeyError: 'name'

that i think its on the `sub = elem.attributes['name'].value`

**EXAMPLE XML FILE**

```
<annotation>
    <folder>Bertukar kertas Jawaban</folder>
    <filename>Data16_12_1.jpg</filename>
    <path>E:\PERKULIAHAN\Pra TA\Data Fix\Bertukar kertas Jawaban\Data16_12_1.jpg</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>1920</width>
        <height>1080</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>Bertukar kertas jawaban</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>860</xmin>
            <ymin>113</ymin>
            <xmax>1196</xmax>
            <ymax>294</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

and for the code, i am trying to take the name and xmin from the xml files
with this code

**CODE**

```
def writeToCSV(frelation):
        csvfile = open('data.csv', 'a+')
        fieldnames = ['name', 'xmin']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        relation = frelation.getElementsByTagName("object")
        for elem in relation:
            sub = elem.attributes['name'].value
            for elem1 in elem.getElementsByTagName("name"):
                sup = elem1.attributes['name'].value
                writer.writerow({'name': sub, 'xmin': sup})

file_id=1;
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/content/drive/MyDrive/DataFix/DataJadi/validation/Bertukar Kertas Jawaban'):
    for file in files:
        if (file.endswith('.xml')):
            xmldoc = parse(os.path.join(root, file))
            frelation = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("annotation")[0]
            relation = frelation.getElementsByTagName("object")
            writeToCSV(frelation,file_id)
            file_id+=1
```

still does not understand how tis works
hope anyone can help
thank you !

Comment: You need to provide a runnable [mre] including at least two (short) sample input files.

Comment: all input files aaare the same just like xml files that i share in this post

Comment: Doesn't matter. You should also indicate the expected/desired results from processing them. Try to make things as clear (and simple) as possible in order to make it easier for others to help you — just saying "it doesn't work" doesn't meet that standard.

Comment: edited, hope this can help people to understand my post, thank you sir @martineau !

Comment: No, no, no! You're making your question worse. Providing a [mre] means taking out everything unrelated to the problem, such as google drive stuff and the `import os`. It also means providing adequate sample input as well as the desired results. The idea is to provide others with enough code and data to reproduce the problem(s) — although ideally there should only be one problem per question.